# Rails—Get all records with same grandparent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, ruby-on-rails-5

I have three models, `Organisation` has many `User` has many `Project`.

How do I query for all `Project` that belong to the same Organisation?

Currently I have `Project.joins(user: [:organisation])`, but that just gets all `Project` and groups them by `User`. I'm not sure how to specify the `Organisation` id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a local variable called `organisation`, which is populated with the Organisation you're interested in, you can add a `where` to your query.

```
Project.joins(user: [:organisation]).where('organisations.id = ?', organisation.id)
```

But it might be more useful to use the associations you have set up (or create new ones)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects
end

class Organisation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :projects, through: :user
end
```

Then you can ask your Organisation for its projects:

```
organisation = Organisation.find(params[:id])
organisation.projects
```